# ASP.NET MVC 3 Route Breaks ActionLink Functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC 2 that I migrated to MVC 3. After migrating, none of my ActionLinks worked anymore. I found it was because of  my default route.

```
routes.MapRoute( "Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

If I change the default route to MVCs default route, it works fine again.

```
routes.MapRoute( "Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Why does having the title optional parameter break my ActionLinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug in the framework. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's not the title parameter being optional that is problematic. In your case it is the id parameter being optional. Only the last parameter of a route definition can be optional and this rule has been enforced in ASP.NET MVC 3. Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846022/can-anyone-recreate-the-following-bug-im-experiencing-in-routes-with-2-or-more-o) on this topic.

So if you want to have such route make sure that you always specify a value for the id parameter when generating those links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("text", "Index", new { id = "123" })
```

Comment: Sorry, Phil Haack just posted that this is a bug.