# Generating RouteUrl in MVC3 returns null in one case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route defined like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Date", "Date/{year}/{month}/{day}", 
    new { controller = "Date", action = "Index", year = UrlParameter.Optional,
         month = UrlParameter.Optional, day = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

So it has 3 optional parameters, year, month and day.  It works fine in routing a GET request, all the following work fine:

```
http://myhost/myapp/Date
http://myhost/myapp/Date/2011
http://myhost/myapp/Date/2011/8
http://myhost/myapp/Date/2011/8/17
```

Generating links using RouteUrl works in all cases except one.

For example, the case where I want a link including the year and a month works fine.  I use the following (simplified) code in my view:

```
 string linkUrl = Url.RouteUrl("Date",
     new { controller = "Date", year = 2011, month = 8 },
     Request.Url.Scheme);
```

But the case where only the year is defined does not work and returns null, the code is:

```
string linkUrl = Url.RouteUrl("Date",
    new { controller = "Date", year = 2011 },
    Request.Url.Scheme);
```

So it all looks correct to me.  Any clue what I'm doing wrong, or how to debug this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it looks like this is a known 'issue' introduced in MVC3, but due to an underlying issue in routing in .NET4, so cannot be quickly fixed by the MVC team.  Although silently returning null is clearly a bug, its unclear whether the route I originally created should be allowed to work the way I wanted it too (see below).

I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846022/can-anyone-recreate-the-following-bug-im-experiencing-in-routes-with-2-or-more-o) which asks for people to replicate a similar issue with two optional parameters, and an answer refers to [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx) too, which has a workaround.

I resolved this as per the workaround by making multiple routes, with only one optional parameter in each.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    "Date-ByDay", // Route name
    "Date/{year}/{month}/{day}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Date", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    "Date-ByMonth", // Route name
    "Date/{year}/{month}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Date", action = "Index", month = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    "Date-ByYear", // Route name
    "Date/{year}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Date", action = "Index", year = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

It is arguable whether my original approach should work anyway, for example what if you miss out the optional 'month' parameter, and should the original route generate a URL of /2011/18?  The 'workaround' whilst ugly, certainly is much more explicit about the behavior you want.   I would argue that the expected behavior of my original route *is* clear (to me) and that I would have expected an exception if I had asked for a route with a year and a day, missing out the month - but I can see that this may not be everyones point of view.  However this *did* work in MVC2.

Comment: as a possible work around, what about just taking one "date" parameter and then working out what type it is in the controller code?

Comment: Date as a string?  With a URL of /Date/08-18-2011?  Perhaps, but I need to display a different view when the browser asks for just the year, or just the year-month.  Thanks though.

Comment: yeah, like that (or maybe with no spaces or slash). Then have some code to check the length to find out what it is, then build the datetime off that?

Comment: That would work fine if I were looking for 'whole dates' all the time.  I'm looking for if the client calls /Date to give a list of all years with data in the database, then /Date/2011 would return all months in 2011 with data. I guess I could pass 00 or 0000 if there were a  missing part.  That almost starts to become more complicated though, and feels a little less RESTful.